# Quickly create and run new C++ files in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode5

I'm learning c++ and I'm building simple, procedural programs that only consist of the one file (where int main() is located). I find it fairly tedious to create a new project in Xcode for each file and I was wondering whether there's a way to either have multiple files in a project and choose which one to compile, or a faster way to create and run/build C++ files in Xcode. I'm currently just commenting programs out as I go and I'd appreciate someone suggesting a better way. I'm open to using Sublime and Command line as well

Comment: To my understanding, Xcode just makes this inconvenient.  It's sad, really.  But ... perhaps I just don't know the answer.  If so, Xcode's interface doesn't make it obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose which files to build and run by changing the Scheme.
I am assuming that you are creating a Console Application / target for each set of files you want to run separately.

go to Product->Scheme and change the Scheme.
Then Build and Run your files.

Answer (score 1):

I think command line is the way to go here. You can easily edit the files in XCode (`open -a Xcode file.cpp`) and compile and run it from the terminal (`clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o name_of_executable file.cpp`).

An alternative to having multiple targets in XCode is to have one command line target and change the file that you compile as a part of the target. In XCode 5 you can show the Utilities panel (top right icon - Hide or show the utilities) and check/uncheck whether a selected file belongs into a target (in the window titled Target Membership). That way you can have a number of files, each having its `main()` but you always have only one file selected as a part of the target.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single project file, then create a new target for each new app instead of a new Xcode project. I'm not sure if that meets your needs or not.

Although if all you're doing is compiling and running a single file, why even use Xcode? Just go to the command line and compile and run it directly, if that's easier. You can invoke `clang` directly. See the `man` page for details.